# Global Search on Custom field in SugarCRM or SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a custom field called code on Accounts module and I want to enable it on the Global Search such that its searches without wildcards entered in the search bar.

So suppose I have some records with values like "88990","23477" and "12347".
If some one uses global search and enters 347 it should return me the account with code 23477 and 12347.
I dont want to enter %347 yo the the results.
How can I achieve this?
I have code on 
custom/Extension/modules/Account/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_code_c.php

```
$dictionary['Account']['fields']['code_c']['inline_edit']='1';
$dictionary['Account']['fields']['code_c']['labelValue']='test code';
$dictionary['Account']['fields']['code_c']['unified_search']=true;
```

and on custom/modules/Accounts/SearchFields.php I have

```
$searchFields['Accounts'] = array(
    'code_c' =>
        array(
            'query_type' => 'default'
        )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

**SuiteCRM Version:** 7.10.4

**Solution is NOT upgrade safe.**

Navigate to include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php and look for the following inside the `generateSearchWhere()` function:

```
$where .= $this->seed->db->concat($concat_table, $concat_fields) . " LIKE " . $this->seed->db->quoted($field_value . $like_char);
$where .= ' OR ' . $this->seed->db->concat($concat_table, array_reverse($concat_fields)) . " LIKE " . $this->seed->db->quoted($field_value . $like_char);
```

I changed this line to concatenate the `$like_char` variable before `$field_value`:

```
$where .= $this->seed->db->concat($concat_table, $concat_fields) . " LIKE " . $this->seed->db->quoted($like_char . $field_value . $like_char);
$where .= ' OR ' . $this->seed->db->concat($concat_table, array_reverse($concat_fields)) . " LIKE " . $this->seed->db->quoted($like_char . $field_value . $like_char);
```